# Construct a tree with list of String and count

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a `Map<List<String>,Integer>` where each entry is a path (`List<String>`) and a count

Ex:

```
["a1", "a2", "a3"] => 4
["a1", "a2"] => 2
["b1", "b2", "b3"] => 3
["b1"] => 4
["b1", "b2"] => 3
["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"] => 5
```

I want to output a tree with count for each node

Tree:

```
- ROOT
-- a1 : 6
--- a2 : 6
---- a3 : 4
-- b1 : 7
--- b2 : 3
-- c1 : 5
--- c2 : 5
---- c3 : 5
----- c4 : 5
```

JSON Structure:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "count": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "count": "",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

What can be the most efficient data-structure and then how to use it in this case (the tree should be then serialized into a JSON tree)?

Comment: how is the tree to be serialized in JSON. Can you give an example? Why the keys are lists, not single values? Why the different number of dashes in front of the different keys?

Comment: Your original structure seems way to complicated, any reason why you have opted for such a structure instead of a more traditional tree structure using Nodes?

Comment: Can you post an example of the expected JSON?

Comment: @atomman yes because I have a list of path and I can't rely on a separator (because I have no idea about the content of a path), so I kept the list

Comment: @fge the JSON should simply represent a Tree where each node contains an array of children and a count

Comment: @JohnJohnGa there is no such thing as a tree in JSON, either objects or arrays, or primitive types (number, null, boolean, string). So please, post an example of the expected JSON.

Comment: @JohnJohnGa would it be possible to use the list of paths instead? It may be easier to work with. Another note, how should the map be interpreted, `List<String>` is the path and the `Integer` the cost of that path?

Comment: @fge I mean { name: "", count: "", children: [{ name: "", count: "", children: [], ... }]}

Comment: @JohnJohnGa Then why doesn't `c1` have a cost of 5, while `a1` does? I fail to see the logic behind your structure. :/ You it would benefit you if you took the answers from these comments and explained it some more in your question.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I would have to agree with @CodeChimp, the easiest way would be translating you `Map` into a `Node` structure then use XStream (or similar) to serialize into JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a tree structure using Nodes, then use XStream to serialize the structure. Examples below, hope this helps you out.

**Convertion to Node structure**

```
public static Node createNodes(Map<List<String>, Integer> map) {
    Map<String, Node> namemap = new HashMap<String, Node>();
    Node root = new Node();
    Node current;
    for (Entry<List<String>, Integer> path : map.entrySet()) {
        current = root;
        for (String nodename : path.getKey()) {
            Node p;
            if (!namemap.containsKey(nodename)){
                p = new Node(nodename, path.getValue());
                namemap.put(nodename, p);
            }else {
                p = namemap.get(nodename);
                p.addCost(path.getValue());
            }
            current.addChild(p);
            current = p;
        }

    }

    return root;
}
```

**Serialization**

```
public static String toXML(Node n) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
    xstream.alias("node", Node.class);
    return xstream.toXML(n);
}
```

**Node Object**

```
public class Node {

    private String name;
    private int count;
    private List<Node> children;

    public Node() {
        this(null, 0);
    }

    public Node(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name; 
        this.count = count;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }


    public void addChild(Node n) {
        for (Node nn : children) {
            if (nn.name.equals(n.name)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        this.children.add(n);
    }

    public void addCost(int i) {
        this.count += i;
    }
}
```

**JSON output**

```
{"node": {
  "count": 0,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "c1",
      "count": 5,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "c2",
          "count": 5,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "c3",
              "count": 5,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "c4",
                  "count": 5,
                  "children": [
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "b1",
      "count": 10,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "b2",
          "count": 6,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "b3",
              "count": 3,
              "children": [
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "a1",
      "count": 6,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "a2",
          "count": 6,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "a3",
              "count": 4,
              "children": [
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me, personally, I would create a Node class that has children and my count value, then tell your JSON serializer how to serialize it properly for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your Map to:

```
Map<String[], Integer>
```

if you want to stay with List, then use `ArrayList` and `trim(`) it.

Then you have to decide if you use a `HashMap`, or if you really want a tree (`TreeMap`).
In the later case you should create an Path object, with a field `String[]` or `List<String>`.
This Path object then must implement `Comparable`, which you habe to implement.

To perform a `Serialisation` (Json or others systems), you usually will writing out the key-value pairs. On reading back again you will build up your map or tree again by feeding in the (key, value) pairs.

It is not a good idea to have the tree structure in the json or otherwise serialized file. You will nearly never need that.